# Grammatical role and meaning of "looking that"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

What are the grammatical role and meaning of the "looking that" in the following sentences?:

> One other painting I really want you to look at is of a young woman
>   surrounded by pumpkins. You will notice that the woman's face is so
>   realistic **looking that** it's almost like a photograph. The woman's
>   nose is a little less than perfect and her hair is kind of messed up.
>   This is realism.

Comment: "Looking that" is not a coherent phrase here.  Instead, "the woman's face is so realistic-looking" is similar to "the woman's face looks so realistic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not split the words up correctly. It should be read:

> the woman's face is so realistic-looking, that it's almost like a photograph

The compound "realistic-looking" is an adjective, that describes the face in the painting.  The whole phrase has the same structure as:

> it is so hot that it burns.

The word "that" is a conjunction. It introduces a subordinate clause that expresses an effect.